# How to create own "save project as" to save all files in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, project

I was wondering if it is possible to create something like
in the visual studio or other bigger environments where you can
save all the project files ?

In my react project user have to read 3 files
(one with columns, one with rows and one with other features).

Then in the app user makes calculations etc.

And at the end of the work the user has to save all three files.

I was wondering if i can somehow do such thing like "save project files"
and all 3 files will be saved and maybe one additional with my own extension?

For example .myApp ? It could be paths to these 3 files or idk... so that i could 
somehow read only this one file and it would show up as all three of them where loaded.

I didn't find anything in google and don't actually know how it is called...
Does anyone have that knowledge and could help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, you can implement such a feature. There are a few things to consider first. An app running in a browser has very limited access to the local file system for security reasons. Most likely you need to save these "files" on a server where your app has access, not in the local file system. I suggest starting by figuring out the details to save a single file in this way. From there saving all project files should be pretty trivial.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice i have saving all of them (one by one) in the local file system. (User clicks on the button and can save one - i created blob with "a href " to do this). One of the files is json , one is .csv and one is xml

Comment: Then you can make a "Save All" button that saves all of the files at once. You might need to refactor your code into reusable functions to do this more easily.

Comment: Yes i can do that, but i can't load them all in once. That is what i need most. In the final app users will have the ability to work even on more files. But to read the file user clicks the button and chooses from the file system. And the user does this one by one... It might be really inconvenient. So i'd like to create "project" where all the files will be. And the posibility to read them and once would be awesome too.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice do you have any tutorials or anything which could help me do that?

Comment: browser can't do that ... it's possible in apps done f.e. in  electron